# Server side script to get facebook access token

Tags: jquery, facebook, perl, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Apologies if this was asked before, I had a look but couldn't quite find any posts that answer my question (at least in a way I understood).

This question is about the Facebook API and authentication.

I have created a script using JQuery which loads a public stream or wall or whatever its called using the Graph API. It connects using an access key which I created by registering an App and authenticating it so that it had permission for offline access and to read a stream only and NOT publish it or access anything else really.

I did this using the following authentication address:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?
client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
&scope=read_stream,offline_access
```

Where the App ID is the one I got when registering an APP and the redirect URL is app domain / "website with Facebook login" site url. (I don't plan on using the facebook login for the site)

So, while I have obtained an access token using the above information which is due to expire in 60 days, my question is, Is there some server side script I can use to either renew the access token (from what I've read there isn't?) or obtain a new one.

As it stands, everything works but I don't want to upload this website and then have to renew an access token every 60 days so it functions properly.

Comment: use php sdk from facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain pretty much permanent access to a public stream using an [application access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-as-app/).

Comment: I have an application access token, but when I created it, the response had an "expires" field which had a value of 60 days (in seconds)

Comment: If it has an expiration, you have a **user** access token, not an **application** access token. The only field you should get back when you debug an application access token is the App Id.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think what I was doing was authorizing the site to access my own personal Facebook account. I think I've done it correctly now as I was just given an access token that contained my app id followed by a | and then an additional string or numbers and characters. No expiration time or anything else really. Does that sound correct ?

Comment: Yes. That sounds correct. You can verify this in the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)